# Как изменить содержимое уведомления без его повторного пересоздания?

Tags: java, android, уведомления

Имеется уведомление, которое обновляется через какой-то определенный промежуток времени. С ним также связана `Foreground` служба, поэтому оно отображается постоянно. При обновлении данных приходится пересоздавать уведомление с новыми, путем использования `NotificationManager`

```
    NotificationManager notificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

    notification.setContentText("Некоторый новый текст");
    notificationManager.notify(NOTIFY_ID, notification.build());
```

При использовании такого метода, каждый раз приходит уведомление, которое отображается как новое на экране блокировки, а также издается звук и вибрация, при его получении.

Можно ли сделать так, чтобы данные обновлялись уже в имеющемся уведомлении, без необходимости его пересоздавать?
Например, как это сделано в приложении погоды, где данные регулярно обновляются прямо в текущем уведомлении:

[image: Виджет погоды в уведомлениях]

Comment: Исходя из типа сообщения, оно никогда не должно сопровождаться звуком и вибро, отключите их просто. А вообще стоит почитать основы: https://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/509-android-notifications-osnovy.html

Comment: @Valeriy В той статье не дается ответа на мой вопрос, а именно что рассказываются основы. Мало того, она датируется 2017 годом и не учитывает API 26 и выше.

Comment: @ShandorHachimann, а что изменилось с API 26? И какие возникают проблемы с примером по обновлению данных из примера на том сайте?

Comment: При использовании одного и того-же канала (NotificationChannel) уведомление не пересоздается, а обновляется. Для того чтобы убрать звук используйте NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_MIN

Comment: вы должны использовать тот же самый `NotificationCompat.Builde` для обновления данных уведомления.